# Test code question

Tags: unit-test

I have a class which has 0% code coverage, but has this schedule class written for it which seems to be conducting a test. My question is this : Is this schedule attempting to run another test class titled test_BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans ? I can't find that class anywhere in the system.

Here is the schedule class :

```
global class ScheduleBatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans implements Schedulable { /*
    Schedulable job for BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions class.
*/
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

        BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions bs = new BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions();
        bs.query = 'SELECT Id, Year__c, current_year__c from monthly_transaction__c' ;
        Database.executeBatch(bs);
    }

    static testMethod void test_BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans() {    
        Test.startTest();

         Account newAcct = new Account(
            name='Test',
            BillingCountry='USA',
            Site='Multinational',
            Total_YTD_Air_Spend_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Hotel_Spend_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Car_Spend_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Rail_Spend_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Air_Transactions_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Hotel_Transactions_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Car_Transactions_CDS__c=0,
            Total_YTD_Rail_Transactions_CDS__c=0
            );

        insert newAcct;

        Monthly_Transaction__c newRecord = new Monthly_Transaction__c(Year__c = '2010', Account__c = newAcct.Id);
        insert newRecord;

        BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions bs = new BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions();
        bs.query = 'SELECT Id, Year__c, current_year__c from monthly_transaction__c' ;
        Database.executeBatch(bs);
        Test.stopTest();  
    }
     }
```

Here is the actual class :

```
global class BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions implements Database.Batchable<Sobject> {
/*
    Job is used to sync up all existing Monthly_Transaction__c records to flag if they are in the given year.

    This will be scheduled to run monthly on the 1st of the month (really the January one is only necessary,
    but you can schedule a job at a minimum of once a month)

    It can also be run via Execute Anonymous, by running the following code:

    BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions bs = new BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions();
    bs.query = 'SELECT Id, Year__c, current_year__c from monthly_transaction__c' ;
    Database.executeBatch(bs);

*/
    public String query; 

    global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, Sobject[] trans) {

        if (trans.size() > 0) {

            List<Monthly_Transaction__c> updateList = new List<Monthly_Transaction__c>();           
            Date currentDate = Date.today();    
            String currentYearString = String.valueOf(currentDate.year());

            System.debug('current System Year : ' + currentYearString);

            for (Sobject mTrans: trans) {
                Monthly_Transaction__c tranUpdate = (Monthly_Transaction__c)mTrans;
                System.debug('record Year : ' + tranUpdate.Year__c);
                if (tranUpdate.Year__c == currentYearString)
                    tranUpdate.Current_Year__c = true;
                else 
                    tranUpdate.Current_Year__c = false;
                updateList.add(tranUpdate);
            }

            if (!updateList.isEmpty())
                update updateList;
        }      
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //Method for post processing operations
    }    
}
```

So, is that schedule class referring to a separate test class ? I'm confused because both the schedule and the main class have 0% code coverage.

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually testing the batch class, you are not testing the scheduled class.  If you test the scheduled class, it should cover both the scheduled class and the batch class.

In your test method, try something like this instead

```
    test.starttest();
    ScheduleBatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans schedBatch= new ScheduleBatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans (); 
    String chron = '0 0 12 * * ?';        
    system.schedule('Test Sched', chron, schedBatch);
    test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Dunc. But I'm confused on what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting I put that test code into the Schedule class ? If so, where should it go ? I'm sorry for the extremely rookie questions. I am completely new to test code.

Comment: It looks like @amatorVitae has demonstrated how to take this snippet I provided and really build out a full test class.  He is testing both the scheduled class and the batch class.  Its worth noting that this will get you the code coverage, but should still have some assertions added to test your logic

Answer (score 3):

The `test code` for the batch is a really good way to do it!  The answer Dunc44 posted will get you test coverage, but it doesn't verify anything that the batch code is supposed to do (so what is it helping?).

The point of the `batch test code` is to verify the batch code does what it's supposed to do.  I suggest creating another `testMethod` and put Dunc44's answer there (call it the `schedule test code`).  Let the `schedule test code` verify the scheduling feature and have the already written `batch test code` verify the batch code functionality.

---

**Update:**

Test Code Example:

```
@istest public BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions_test{

    private static testMethod batchCode(){
        Account acct = newAcctList(1)[0];
        insert acct;

        list<Monthly_Transaction__c> monthTransList = newMonthlyTransList(1,acct);
        insert monthTransList;

        test.startTest();

        // your test code

        test.stopTest();

        // verify your results

    }//END batchCode

    private static testMethod testSchedule(){
        Account acct = newAcctList(1)[0];
        insert acct;

        list<Monthly_Transaction__c> monthTransList = newMonthlyTransList(1,acct);
        insert monthTransList;

        test.startTest();

        ScheduleBatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans schedBatch= new ScheduleBatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTrans (); 
        String chron = '0 0 12 * * ?';        
        system.schedule('Test Sched', chron, schedBatch);

        test.stopTest();

    }//END testSchedule


    //---------  Helper Static Methods   ----------------
      // *** just an example ***
    public static list<Monthly_Transaction__c> newMonthlyTransList(integer num, Account a){
        list<Monthly_Transaction__c> returnList = new Monthly_Transaction__c();
        for(integer i=0;i<num;i++){
            returnList.add(new Monthly_Transaction__c(
                Year__c = '2010', 
                Account__c = a.Id
            ));
        }    
        return returnList;
    }//END newMonthlyTransList

    public static list<Account> newAcctList(integer num){
        list<Account> returnList = new list<Account>();

        for(integer i=0;i<num;i++){
            returnList.add(new Account(
                name='Test-'+string.valueOf(i),
                BillingCountry='USA',
                Site='Multinational',
                Total_YTD_Air_Spend_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Hotel_Spend_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Car_Spend_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Rail_Spend_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Air_Transactions_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Hotel_Transactions_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Car_Transactions_CDS__c=0,
                Total_YTD_Rail_Transactions_CDS__c=0
            ));
        }
        return returnList;
    }//END newAcctList


}//END BatchSyncYearOnMonthlyTransactions_test
```

Comment: can you show me what you're suggesting ? I'm a total rookie and am at a great loss here. Should it go into the Scheduler class ? Thanks so much.

Comment: The batch class should certainly be tested, but the code to do that doesn't really belong inside a testmethod for in some different class. If I wanted to change the batch logic later on, I wouldn't naturally look inside a Schedulable Class to fix the testmethod that runs the batch.

Comment: I updated my answer to give an example, Zoom_v.  Enjoy!